# Shell script invocation error - deleted Fabric framework remains in project

Tags: objective-c, shell, compiler-errors, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I've added Fabric/Crashlytics framework into my project manually (not via Cocoapods) before, and then deleted both manually too. This error showed up at the compile time:

```
/Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-hgnmlcwlcxdbmqdzjjegfjbdmxsy/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.build/Script-800A33631A8B53890076A7E8.sh: line 2: ./Fabric.framework/run: No such file or directory
```

I found the .sh file in the path and tried to delete it, but that file got generated automatically every time I run the project:

[image]

Please help me fix this hour burner...

Here's the entire error message if needed: [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rd5wokxdpcwcwvd/ShellScriptInvocation.rtf?dl=0)

Answer (score 4):

This still happens in

`[Crashlytics] Version 3.7.0 (102)`.

You have to change file permissions for both the script

`chmod 755 ./YourApp/SDK/Fabric/Fabric.framework/run`

and the executable

`chmod 755 /YourApp/SDK/Fabric/Fabric.framework/uploadDSYM`

Answer (score 0):

If the script *doesn't* need to be executed (which I'm guessing since you tried to delete it). You can always try this workaround:

```
$ script="/Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-hgnmlcwlcxdbmqdzjjegfjbdmxsy/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.build/Script-800A33631A8B53890076A7E8.sh"
$ awk 'NR==2 { print "exit 0;" } { print }' "$script" > .tmp && mv .tmp "$script"
```

Which adds an exit between the first and second line of the script. If the file gets regenerated you can also work around that by changing permissions:

```
$ sudo chmod 111 "$script"
```

This way the file should be protected from being overwritten or re-created.

Comment: thanks for quick reply! I got < chmod: fts_open: No such file or directory > after typing < $ sudo chmod 111 "$file" >  ...

Comment: Yea sorry, my bad that's a typo. Try `sudo chmod 111 "$script"`. But first execute the first two lines too `$ script=...` and `awk ...`, so the variable script is set.

Comment: `awk: can't open file /Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-hgnmlcwlcxdbmqdzjjegfjbdmxsy/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.build/Script-800A33631A8B53890076A7E8.sh
 source line number 1` ...awkward printout

Comment: Haha good pun there, just open the file manually using `sudo nano` and add `exit 0;` between the first and second line. Then `chmod 111`.

Comment: Well...that Script.sh file did not re-generate surely! while the error still showed up =/ here's how the script look like: `#!/bin/sh
exit 0;
chmod 111
./Fabric.framework/run a40551c9dde24199606cf656a77a924f43ddc800 dd2e9a187d355b3$d355b3d57d7$ `sorry for knowing nothing about the workaround.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps:

Step : 1 : **open your path** (/Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-hgnmlcwlcxdbmq‌​dzjjegfjbdmxsy/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Projec‌​tName.build/Script-800A33631A8B53890076A7E8.sh) with **go to folder** from finder.

Step : 2 : There open your "Script-800A33631A8B53890076A7E8.sh" file

Step : 3 : Modify  .sh file as shown below

```
#!/bin/sh 
 exit 0; chmod 111 //add this after building has started and save

./Fabric.framework/run <FABRIC API KEY> <FABRIC API SECRET>
```

Comment: exit 0 is simply bypassing the rest of the lines. you are just skipping the script.

Comment: @Saqib Saud Ok.I have just tried avoid exception if any issue fabric framework while app archiving ,which worked for me to submit my app to App Store.. .But do you know the solution for this to execute so that I will try with that..

Comment: Im working on a solution, will update it once im successful.